# Dozer: CustomerConverter that is Internationalization/Localization aware, how to implement?

Tags: java, javabeans, dozer

I have not yet used Dozer, but Dozer seems promising. I have read quite a lot of the documentation but I am still completely clueless about what I need to do to write a CustomConverter that is localization/internationalization aware:

Example: I want to convert String values to Dates, depending on the locale. I have a DTO (without the locale) and of course the locale (from the ServletContainer=>Browser). How am I able to inject the locale to the CustomConverter or the mapping process, so that I can use it for a locale specific Conversion and I get access to the locale object? (And more generically, how to in general inject some kind of "contextobject" that i can use in the converter...

I would be very thankfull for stating the very rough steps how this would be implemented/if this is possible. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a custom bean factory to create and initialize the dto with a locale parameter.

http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custombeanfactories.html
http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customCreateMethod.html